# Rotate y axis TEXT labels in plot.zoo

Tags: r, plot, zoo

I would like to rotate the labelling of the y-labs to horizontal and can't find an answer without ggplot.

Is there a way to rotate them in plot.zoo?

The labels I mean are those ones called Series 1:5 and I have outlined them in red.

```
data <- xts(matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 5), order.by = as.Date(1:200))
plot.zoo(data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `las=1` like this:

```
plot.zoo(data, las = 1)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Update

The question later clarified that it was referring to the ylab.  plot.zoo uses mtext for that and hard codes it; however, we could hack it using `trace`:

```
library(xts)

trace(plot.zoo, 
  quote(mtext <- function(...) graphics::mtext(..., cex = 0.7, las = 1)))
plot.zoo(data, oma = c(6, 5, 5, 0))
untrace(plot.zoo)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That's what I don't want, this is described in many other posts. I want to rotate the y-axis description. The ones called Series.